# Creating geodatabase from CSV using python

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, arcpy, esri-geodatabase, interpolation

I have a file with weather data (daily) for multiple weather stations for multiple years. I am looking for some python script to automate the database creation process and its interpolation on a daily basis. The weather data looks like this:

```
YEAR    MONTH   DAY     Date        STID    TMAX    TMIN    TAVG
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    WENT    72.63   44.02   58.27
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    DKOM    70.66   40.77   55.76
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    OLLU    73.15   33.47   51.67
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    LKNP    -999    -999    -999
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    OWNB    70.88   32.01   52.2
2000    1       1       1/1/2000    ANTL    71.85   31.13   51.66
```

There is a separate shapefile that is associate with the location of the weather stations. How do I create database using python script so that it can be used later for spatial interpolation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the shapefile relate to the CSV file? `STID`?

Comment: Shapefile has STID with its lat/long, STID is unique

Answer (score 8):

```
<begin shameless plug>
```

In 2008 I wrote "[Tapping Into the Power of Python: Data mining, data processing, logging, and e-mails](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0708/files/tappingpython.pdf)" for ArcUser. [Here are the code listings](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0708/files/tappingpython.txt) - some of the code is outdated, but the concepts could be helpful.

```
<end shameless plug>
```

Comment: Great article, Chad! @Kenton it would be a great exercise to get the tabular data for your weather stations directly from the internet as in Listing 3.

Answer (score 7):

1. I would first design the schema of your desired feature class either using [ArcGIS Diagrammer](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geodatabase-Gallery/details?entryID=F12ADF8F-1422-2418-34B2-C276C6BCCF98) or through ArcCatalog. Save this in a file geodatabase which will be used solely as a template.
2. Next use [Copy (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000051000000) to copy the template file geodatabase to the desired location, renaming it if necessary.
3. Next, use [Make Feature Layer (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006p000000) and [Make Table View (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006v000000) to create a feature layer from your shapefile and a table view from your CSV file.
4. Next, use [Add Join (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000) to join the table view to the feature layer on `STID`.
5. Finally, use [Append (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000) with the appropriate [field mappings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000s000000) to append the contents of the feature layer with the join to the template feature class in the new file geodatabase.

   **Tip:** Do the Append step interactively in ArcCatalog with the field mappings set up as desired and then go to the Results tab, right click the result entry and do *"Copy as Python Snippet"* to get the fiddly field mapping string you need. Alternatively you can use the [FieldMappings](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000008q000000) object to create this parameter programmatically.

Apart from the first step (designing the template geodatabase), these can all be scripted easily using arcpy function calls. See the help for each command for example usage.

Comment: In all fairness, the first step can be programmed in python too.  This is the way I would do it otherwise. +1