# From text data create a FeatureClass with table with python

Tags: python, shapefile, arcgis-9.3, csv, feature-dataset

I'm searching how the output of one program (text file with some writings, but also with data as numbers, dates, times, coordinates, all separated with commas) can be transformed to a Feature Dataset.

**1) .txt -> .csv -> gp.TabletodBase** and then it's nearly done..
But get problems writing csv with Excel dialect - all row is writen in one cell. So, I create the delimiter ';' to get the data into cell by cell.

```
f= open(rawtable, 'r')
f2 = open(outtable, 'wb')
csv.register_dialect('dotcoma', delimiter=';')
writer=csv.writer(f2, dialect='dotcoma')

for line in itertools.islice(f, 6, 7): #reading labels that are in 6'th row
    labels= line.strip('\n').split(",")
    writer.writerow(labels)
```

But well, then Arcgis does not recognize the table..
I have been trying to cast the data, like integers, floats, strings.. but that did not help..

> **2) .txt -> .shp...**   ----> THAT WORKS!!!

The shapefile does not have a type of time.. So was skiping it.

*EDITED*
However tried the Pyshp library. But after creating fields blindly I record the tuple of all data in a row and I'm getting an error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`..

I simply write fields from the list of data, depending to which group they go:

```
for fieldname in labelkeys:
    if fieldname in t_int:
        w.field(fieldname, 'N', 8, 0) #1probl was here as I made '8' vs. 8 ! stpd
    ...
    else:
        w.field (fieldname,'C', 25)
```

Another problem with coordinates. I was writing floats... and it did not like it.. So I had to write integers.
Plus one cannot pass a tuple to w.record(). 
Thanks to StackExchange I've learned the benefits of asterix :) and one simply has to write w.record(*mylist).

**3) .txt -> feature class...**
Here I have problems writing the entire row at once..(like the list of values) into a NewRow. Since field names are made automatically I can not for each make like `row.fieldname=somevariable`. I have tried while looping to SetValues  `row.setValue(labelkeys[unit], data[unit])` and then at the end of a list `rows.InsertRow(row)` , but it seemed that it sets just one value. Though I tried by hand and got an error in data casting..

The error comes that I read data like string '34', cast it to int(34) and try to write into field with type 'DOUBLE' (since I grouped some data and wanted to make more generic types).

```
if labelkeys[unit] in t_int:
    if data[unit]:
        row.setValue(labelkeys[unit], int(data[unit]))
```

So for now.. nothing is really working..

Maybe there is some other way I have not though about?

If not, could anyone help to get the things work?...

Comment: Similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20944/creating-geodatabase-from-csv-using-python/20946#20946

Comment: Also, I think you mean featureclass and not feature dataset.

Comment: @ChadCooper indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In version 9.3 there is a toolbox called Create Features from Text File, which can do what you require. The help files are quite detailed and are found [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Create_Features_from_Text_File_%28Samples%29).

The following code sample should be simple enough to adapt to reflect your dataset:

```
# Create geoprocessing dispatch object
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Set up inputs to tool
inTxt = r"C:\temp\StreamPoints.txt"
inSep = "." #the symbol used to indicate a decimal point
output = r"C:\temp\Streams.shp"

# Run tool
gp.CreateFeaturesFromTextFile(inTxt, inSep, output, "#")
```

**UPDATE:**

If you require numerous attributes of a range of types to be written to a feature dataset from a text file or csv file, it my be easiest to use [pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/). I wrote up [an answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/using-the-python-shape-library-pyshp-how-to-convert-csv-file-to-shp/35611#35611) to a similar question about pyshp a few days ago and will reproduce the relevant parts of this answer below.

The pyshp/xbase datatyping has always been tricky for me until I found [this user guide for the xbase format](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~varun/cs315p/xbase.txt) and as a result of this question I have written a small note on [my blog](http://pygis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/pyshp-attribute-types-and-point-files.html) regarding the relevant pyshp datatypes, part of which I have pasted below:

- C is ASCII characters
- N is a double precision integer limited to around 18 characters in length
- D is for dates in the YYYYMMDD format, with no spaces or hyphens between the sections.
- F is for floating point numbers with the same length limits as N
- L is for logical data which is stored in the shapefile's attribute table as a short integer as a 1 (true) or a 0 (false). The values it can receive are 1, 0, y, n, Y, N, T, F or the python builtins True and False

There is a DateTime type as well which should allow you to store correctly formatted time data as well using the same syntax as the above datatypes.

Here is an example python script showing the use of the various pyshp datatypes being read in from lists, which could be populated with your data using the csv module:

```
import shapefile as shp

#Input parameters
out_file = 'GPS_Pts.shp'

#Set up blank lists for data
x,y,id_no=[1.0,2.4,3.9],[4.3,5.5,6.1],[55,16,10]
date,notes = ['20121012','20121012','20121011'],['This','is a','string']
logic = [True,False,True]

#Set up shapefile writer and create empty fields
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.autoBalance = 1 #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
w.field('X','F',10,5)
w.field('Y','F',10,5) #float - needed for coordinates
w.field('Date','D') #date
w.field('Notes','C',50) #string
w.field('ID_N','N',12) #double
w.field('Logic','L',1)#boolean

#loop through the data and write the shapefile
for j,k in enumerate(x):
    w.point(k,y[j]) #write the geometry
    w.record(k,y[j],date[j], notes[j], id_no[j], logic[j]) #write the attributes

#Save shapefile
w.save(out_file)
```

Comment: This tool is used just to create a Features using the coordinates. What I am searching first of all is creating a table with a lot of features.. especially DATE, TIME and so on

Comment: Ah. My apologies, I read the question too fast. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Wow, that's a loooong explanation. Thanks a lot for such explicity, will take time to read and test things :) Just a small rremark about `DateTime` type. I need Time as well and so .shp does not have it.. and so pyshp I guess it's just for .shp. That stays a minus, but just one, compared with so many I have for now..

Comment: Yeah, I just did some more reading and you're right, a third party driver is needed to support datetime in xbase files which the shapefiles cannot use. The date portion does work however, so it may be possible to parse out times and dates into 2 fields, a date field and a double precision integer and use unix time (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to record a precise time which can be converted back to a human readable format within the script. All the best.

Comment: Unfortnatelly, getting an error while wirting a record: 'IndexError: tuple index out of range'. Since I do not know exact field names, just have them in a list, I create the list of casted attributes from the line I read from txt, and simply make it tuple in order to write the whole line at once. Is it possible without saving shp (as I can't that either) to check how many fields were created?

Comment: Such a simplicity that even I found though of :) `w.fields`.. But after checking I see that I have the same length of fields as well as of my tuple I want to write in... But the same error anyways..

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that your tuple is too long or short relative to the other fields, the data must be symmetrical. You could insert print len() statements into your code to see where the data does not match up. Failing that read the data into lists as I have in my example and perform a conditional check on them to ensure they are all the same length: if len(list1)==len(list2)==len(list3):

Comment: Indeed all was matching. First thing, I found that it did not accept coordinates as floats(!), other thing was that I was writing data all casted in tuple `w.record(tuple(casted))`, so it meant 1 unit ! I just needed to parse it like w.record(*casted) to put one by one.

Comment: That's good that its working. I'm surprised about it not accepting coordinates floats, but I'll put that down to ESRI eccentricities!

Comment: Thanks a lot for a help!.
I did not define the CRS, I guess therefore. If one defines it maybe that should accept I hope. Will try it!

Comment: Uf.. those floats turned to be strings (forgot to convert) :S.. So all works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested MakeXYEventLayer? I believe it will create a Feature Layer from a variety of formats, csv, txt, xls, etc. You can then run Copy_features to save the features to Shapefile or file geodatabase. If the field data types aren't interpreted correctly, you can create a blank feature class with data types you require. You can add or remove fields too. Finally, run Append to push your data into the final schema. Identical Field names are automatically mapped by the field mapper.

Comment: First, thought that MakeXYEventLayer is available just manually! 
Will try a bit later, since it worked out with Pyshp